# Are there any websites for keeping score of various boardgames?

Tags: scoring

My friends and I are pretty competitive.  We play a lot of various games with various scoring systems used by each (i.e. 7-wonders, Catan, Dominion, etc...).

Does anybody know of any website or system that can be used for keeping track of who won which game and by how much?  Doesn't need to be applicable to all games, but would be nice to keep a record.

Comment: The fallback of Google Docs spreadsheets is probably decent here. It has the advantage of already having a mobile app, it's easy to share, and you know you can always add another column if you really need it.

Comment: @Jefromi I used to do exactly that, but the main problem with it is that you usually can't do that right after the play is over (e.g. because you're starting a new one), and adding the score using the mobile version is not convenient (for me). The app that I recommend in my answer (http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/32918/5583) solves this problem completely, because adding a new play is so easy and fast. And you can easily export all data to a spreadsheet if you want to add another column or two.

Answer (score 10):

Boardgamegeek (http://boardgamegeek.com) has a play reporting feature which can include who played, what position each played, their score, and additional notes. Play notes can be publicly accessed. (It can be a bit of a pain, tho, to find someone else's plays.)

It does exactly what you're asking for. If the same person reports every time, it's readily viable to find it.

Further, one can create a private geeklist which lists the games, instead of using the play reports feature.

Answer (score 4):

NemeStats (http://nemestats.com) is a new site that is purpose-built to be able to record the results of any game to get interesting statistics like win/loss percentage, list of players you beat the most, players you lose to the most, games you play the most, your average rank in games, etc.

It is mostly geared toward players that play in a stable gaming group but could also be used to record just your own plays against anonymous opponents if you wanted.

**Update as of 2016-02-26: We continue to enhance the site and also have the ability to import your geek list directly into NemeStats to lower the barrier to start creating games.

**Update as of 2016-07-20: We now have integration with the iOS app Board Game Stats -- providing the best web + phone app experience out there!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that [Rankade.com](http://rankade.com) suits your needs.
My friends and I use it to keep score and rankings from over 100 games, and with over 600 matches. You can see the [public page of our group here](https://rankade.com/trepaste).

It's free, with apps for mobile (both iOS and Android) and webapp (which I like more, as it has more charts and features than the app).

I also have different groups for sports or other games, not only boardgames. For example, I think it's nearly perfect for table football and table tennis.

Answer (score 2):

I realize I'm late to the party but check out [shpeely.com](https://shpeely.com). It allows to track all your games and creates statistics for each game and player. Also it has a scoring system that allows you to track your performance *across* games.

Comment: The answer seems fine, so it doesn't matter how late you are.

Answer (score 2):

This is an iOS app (your question mentions not only a website, but a 'system') which is awesome for all boardgame tracking. It has great interface, lots of stats, integration with Boardgamegeek and Nemestats, and much more: [Board Game Stats](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/board-game-stats/id892542000?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4). (I'm just a fan of it)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an App that keeps score for you!

[Keep Score - Score Keeper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.keepscore&hl=en://)

Answer (score 0):

I use the score geek app and it's pretty good. It syncs your plays with board game geek to and has pretty much all of their library available to score.  It's not free though.

[Scoregeek website](http://www.rebrandsoftware.com/app.asphttp://www.rebrandsoftware.com/app.asp?id=34)

Answer (score -1):

There's a Chrome app that appears to do what you are looking for. It's called Scorekeeper. You can find it on the Chrome Web Store by searching "Scorekeeper" or by clicking here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scorekeeper/ognaddcodlklfjfbaghkkoipibeniocp/related?hl=en-US

Comment: This does not appear to be useful for keeping track of victories between various games, as it's just a simplistic card/number system. If it is actually useful for this purpose, could you explain how?